# Form submit with sessions

Tags: php, html

I have a problem with not getting the input values when I submit the form.

With this code there is an overview of domein records, with the ID it reads which one it will edit.

I have to get the values in a $_SESSION wen press edit.

```html
<?php
require_once("classes/Login.php");
require_once("classes/versio.class.php");
require_once("config/config.php");
require_once("includes/includes.php");
require_once("includes/bootstrap.php");
require_once("includes/header.php");

if($login->isUserLoggedIn() != true) {
 header("Location: ./login.php");
}

$domain = $_GET['domain'];
$tld = $_GET['tld'];

unset($command);
$command = array(
 "command" => "DomainsDNSListRecords",
 "domain" => $domain,
 "tld" => $tld
);

$api = new Versio_api();
$versio = $api->api_send($command);

if($versio['success']==0) {
 echo("Fout opgetreden. Fout code: ".$versio['command_response_code'].". Fout text: ".$versio['command_response_message']."");
}
else {
 if($versio['total_count']>0)
 {
require_once("includes/submenu.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $_SESSION["name"] = $_POST['rName'];
 $_SESSION["type"] = $_POST['rType'];
 $_SESSION["value"] = $_POST['rVal'];
 $_SESSION["prio"] = $_POST['rPrio'];
 $_SESSION["ttl"] = $_POST['rTtl'];
}

?>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Klantenpaneel</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
   <form method="post" action="">
    <table class="table table-striped">
     <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>Naam</th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Waarde</th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Prioriteit</th>
      <th></th>
      <th>TTL</th>
      <th></th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
     <tbody>
<?php
 $teller = 1;
 while($versio['total_count']>=$teller) {
?>
       <tr>
      <td><input class="table-input" type="text" name="rName" value="<?php echo $versio['name_'.$teller]; ?>"></td>
      <td><select class="table-input" name="rType">
       <option value="<?php echo $versio['type_'.$teller]; ?>"><?php echo $versio['type_'.$teller]; ?></option>
       <option value="A">A</option>
       <option value="MX">MX</option>
       <option value="CNAME">CNAME</option>
       <option value="SRV">SRV</option>
       <option value="TXT">TXT</option>
       <option value="SPF">SPF</option>
      </select></td>
      <td><input class="table-input" type="text" name="rVal" value="<?php echo $versio['value_'.$teller]; ?>"></td>
      <td><input class="table-input" type="text" name="rPrio" value="<?php echo $versio['prio_'.$teller]; ?>"></td>
      <td><select class="table-input" type="text" name="rTtl">
<?php
 $_SESSION["ttl"] = $versio['ttl_'.$teller];
 $getal = $_SESSION["ttl"];
 $_60 = 60;
 $uitkomst = $getal / $_60 / $_60;
 echo $uitkomst;
?>
       <option value="<?php echo $versio['ttl_'.$teller]; ?>"><?php echo $uitkomst ?> uur</option>
       <option value="300">5 min</option>
       <option value="3600">1 uur</option>
       <option value="7200">2 uur</option>
       <option value="14400">4 uur</option>
       <option value="28800">8 uur</option>
       <option value="86400">24 uur</option>
       </select>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 10px;"><a href="edit.record.php?id=<?php echo $versio['id_'.$teller]; ?>&tld=<?php echo $tld ?>&domain=<?php echo $domain ?>" style="color:blue; text-decoration:none;" 
          onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Edit this item?');">
      <p class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil text-primary" type="submit" name="submit"></p></a></td>
      <td style="width: 10px;"><a href="remove.record.php?id=<?php echo $versio['id_'.$teller]; ?>&tld=<?php echo $tld ?>&domain=<?php echo $domain ?>" style="color:red; text-decoration:none;" 
          onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');">
      &#10008;</a></td>
       </tr>
<?php      $teller++;
}
?>
     </tbody>
    </table>
    <a href="add.record.php?domain=<?php echo $domain ?>&tld=<?php echo $tld ?>">
      Record toevoegen</a>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
<?php
 } else {
  echo("Er zijn geen DNS records gevonden voor dit domein.");
 }
}
?>

<?php require_once("includes/footer.php"); ?>
```

```html
<?php
require_once("classes/versio.class.php");

$domain = $_GET['domain'];
$tld = $_GET['tld'];
$id = $_GET['id'];

unset($command);
$command = array(
 "command" => "DomainsDNSDeleteRecord",
 "domain" => $domain,
 "tld" => $tld,
 "id" => $id
); 
 
 $api = new Versio_api();
 $versio = $api->api_send( $command );
 
if($versio['success']==0) {
 echo("Fout opgetreden. Fout code: ".$versio['command_response_code'].". Fout text: ".$versio['command_response_message']."");
} else {

 unset($command);
 $command = array(
  "command" => "DomainsDNSAddRecord",
  "domain" => $domain,
  "tld" => $tld,
  "name" => $_SESSION['name'],
  "type" => $_SESSION['type'],
  "value" => $_SESSION['value'],
  "prio" => $_SESSION['prio'],
  "ttl" => $_SESSION['ttl']
 );

  $api = new Versio_api();
  $versio = $api->api_send($command);

  if($versio['success']==0) {
   echo("Fout opgetreden. Fout code: ".$versio['command_response_code'].". Fout text: ".$versio['command_response_message']."");
   
  }else{
   header ("location: records.php?domain=$domain&tld=$tld");
  }
} 
?>
```

Comment: Have you called `session_start();` wherever you use `$_SESSION`(s)?

Comment: Yes that's included on every page.

Comment: have you check if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {} this condition become true or not after submit

Comment: It becomes true when you submit but the session will be empty...